# How to revert back to a branch before merging and keep the changes made after merging

Tags: git

Problem:

I have branches A, B.  B was merged into A and changes in A were made after that. I want to revert back to A before being merged with B and keep the changes that were made after the merge.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, your repository looks like this.

```
1 - 2 --------- 7 - 8 [A]
     \         /
      4 - 5 - 6 [B]
```

B branched off A at commit 2. Committed 4, 5 and 6. Then merged back into A at 7. Then another commit, 8, was made on A.

If you didn't delete B, it's still there. If you did, you'll have to find the original commit and restore the branch label. You can do this with `git log --graph --decorate --oneline A`. You'll see something like...

```
* (A) 4f8cea2 Some commit
* 9a7fd82 Merge B into A
|\  
| * c772b6d some commit on B
| * c9178a2 another commit on B
| * d7a579d a commit on B
|/
* b4d1b73 The commit before B
```

In this case `c772b6d` is the last commit on B.

```
git branch B c772b6d
```

That will restore B.

---

To restore A, do an interactive rebase back to commit 2. Again, use `git log` to find that commit. In our example it's `b4d1b73`. So checkout A and rebase back to there.

```
git checkout A
git rebase -i b4d1b73
```

You'll get an editor like this:

```
pick 4f8cea2 Some commit
pick c772b6d some commit on B
pick c9178a2 another commit on B
pick d7a579d a commit on B
```

These are all the commits between A and b4d1b73, but no merge commits. The rebase will flatten A. Now delete the commits from B leaving only the commits on A.

```
pick 4f8cea2 Some commit
```

Then save and Git will write only the remaining commits on top of `b4d1b73`. You'll have...

```
1 - 2 - 8' [A]
     \         
      4 - 5 - 6 [B]
```

If you get into trouble with the rebase, the original version of A is pointed at by ORIG_HEAD. You can restore it with `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`.